# Как можно передать значения из Javabeans в JS

Tags: javascript, jsf

Есть код верстки страницы на JSF и в том числе форма,данные заполнения которой отправляются в JavaBeans.
Как можно потом их получить в JS?

Задание таково:есть форма где надо заполнить координаты точек.После ввода эта точка должна появится на графике.Ну,и так же точку можно выбирать и щелкнув на графике.
А для этого в JS надо знать все координаты всех точек.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разместить на форме скрытое поле, в котором хранить все координаты. Значение для поля получать из `JavaBeans`. Написать `JavaScript`, который будет искать поле по идентификатору, извлекать данные, парсить их, и передавать в график.

PS Обычно, `JSF-приложения` строятся с использованием расширений (`PrimeFaces`, `MyFaces` и др). В большинстве распространённых `JSF-расширений` есть хорошие реализации различных графиков, работающие с `JavaBeans`, и не требующие работы с `JavaScript-ом`.

Comment: Как в h:inputHidden передать javaBean?Так не работает:<h:inputHiddenvalue="#{point.x}"/>

Comment: Не сам bean, а обращение к его свойству через get/set методы. Должно работать именно так value="#{point.x}". Попробуйте для начала вместо inputHidden применить, например, h:outputText, чтобы наглядно увидеть что происходит

Answer (score 0):

Что вам мешает использовать для этого атрибут `onclick` у какой-нибудь кнопки `<h:commandButton/>` и в нем вызвать JS функцию с параметром: `testJS(#{javaBean.dotX})`, передавая параметр посредством EL выражения.

Для передачи более сложных структур данных рекомендую ознакомиться с библиотекой [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).
Советую прочитать также пример работы с ней в [похожей теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561725/how-to-pass-a-list-to-javascript-in-jsf) с вашим вопросом.